# All buttons on the page are getting disabled after compare validation

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have written a compare validator to check if the start date is greater than the end date, and I am displaying a message for the same and its working fine.

the issue is that, all buttons on the page are getting disabled after the validation check, my text box has a small button (calender) button next to it, which on clicking will display the selected date in the text box next to it.

Since all the buttons are by default getting disabled, I am not able to change the date, and hence the page is stuck. How do I disable only the submit button on the page and let all the buttons remain "enabled" by default ?

code :

```
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAlertCreatiFino" runat="server" CssClass="style33" Width="100px"
             MaxLength="8" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton8" ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar_icon.gif" 
             runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton8_Click" />
        <span class="float_calendar">
            <span class="style20">
         <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar8" runat="server" 
                      OnSelectionChanged="Calendar8_SelectionChanged"
                      Visible="False" CellPadding="4" DayNameFormat="Shortest"> 
          </asp:Calendar>
             </span>
       </span>                       
        <asp:CompareValidator id="CmpAlertCreatiDate" Text="validation"
    ControlToValidate="txtAlertCreatiFino"  ControlToCompare="txtAlertCreatiDa"
    Type="Date" Operator="GreaterThan" SetFocusOnError = "true"
    Runat="server" EnableViewState="true"/>   
</td>
<td class="style16">
    <span class="style28" />
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: put you code here for understanding your problem.

Comment: as we can see in the above code, next to the text box, i have a calender button, which on clicking will display the date in the text box, now these buttons are also getting disabled, I want only the submit button to get disabled and all other buttons remain enabled.

Comment: can someone pelase ans my Q